# Expose SQL Server stored procedures on a web API

Tags: c#, sql-server, proxy, asp.net-web-api

I'm not sure whether this is a Stack Overflow question, but here goes...

Let's say you have two sites:

- Site A hosts a publicly accessible web API that uses a NoSQL database at the same site and a bunch of web applications.
- Site B hosts a SQL Server (not the same data as the site A NoSQL database) and some other web applications.

The problem is that the web API at site A needs to access the SQL Server at site B for some of its functionality. You could expose the SQL Server IP and make stored proc calls that way, but would it be possible to create a generic web API that would be hosted on site B and would proxy SQL calls from site A? You wouldn't want to expose your SQL Server IP, right?

It would be possible if you create a method for every stored proc you want to call on the web API, but would it not be possible to avoid that and have a generic proxy?

Let me know if I'm going in the wrong direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a ASP.NET MVC site with a controller that uses reflection to figure out which repository method the client is trying to call depending on the parameters that were passed in. So it's basically an API for calling SQL procs remotely. It has authentication, of course. It is hosted at site B.

Site A hosts a site that calls the API and gets the data.

EDIT:

[WCF Data Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) would have solved this problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe seems to be a tunnel for SQL server over web api. I wouldn't encourage it.

Instead of looking at the two systems as SQL Server database v/s NoSQL database, I would look at the services to abstract them into domain entities.

If the two systems need to exchange data, it would be in the form of these entities. The reasons I feel this way:

1. Keep the systems isolated, schema changes need not affect downstream systems.
2. Allows the flexibility to encapsulate the internals of one system so that designing the consumer can be contract driven.

Edit:

I discourage this because

1. This tends to have a tangled setup, Site A now talks raw data that it does not own or control. You could easily be in a position where the SQL server needs changes demanded by B and this makes A very brittle (things break very easily).
2. Business changes/logic not relevant to A can creep in via DDL etc changes made by B.

I would prefer having a very loose coupling between A and B. Define ownership of data and other consumers would need to communicate via a contract.

Comment: I forgot to clarify that the NoSQL and SQL Server databases store different data. The web API on site A needs to use both databases. But yes, it is a tunnel over a web API. Why would you discourage it?

Comment: Have added a couple of points to my answer, besides this there is also a potential security hole, particularly if the API is over internet.